# No-thanks: What if a player has no card? | If a player hoards cards?

Tags: no-thanks

In No-thanks, according to the rulebook:

> When finally a player decides to take the card (and all chips next to
>   it), he puts it in front of himself face-up and takes the chips up in
>   hand. After that, this player turns over the next card of the deck.

So assuming, player C took the card that players A, and B declined. So he now has that card + 2 chips. He then turns over the card and lucky him, it's a card close to his first card so he took it again, and the cycle repeats until there's only a few cards left in the deck.

We played the game and there was a specific scenario like this that luckily for one person, even though the shuffling was a bit random, the cards were close together that he just took almost all the cards (but of course in the end, he lost because there were gaps). But how about other players who weren't able to get a card due to one person's hoarding? Does that mean they get negative points (due to the chips plus the fact that they don't have a card)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, did you remember to randomly remove 9 cards from the deck? This would greatly reduce the chance of a player getting lucky enough for that to be a good idea.

Other than that, it is certainly possible that a player could get negative points (though I don't think I've seen it happen). If you have a player that is purposefully losing the game by just taking every card, and thus making the game unplayable for the other players, then it is simply an issue of sportsmanship, and not one of rules. The rules do not prevent a player from ruining the game in this way.

Comment: Thanks @GendolKari, and yes we did randomly removed 9 cards from the deck. Although random, the 9 cards were majority the high value cards. Then one of the players, out of luck again from the deck, managed to get low numbered cards in somewhat of a sequence (probably due to bad shuffling) hence, he was able to hoard cards and one other player got nothing. So, in the case of that scenario, would the player with no cards win as he gets negative points along with his chips?

Comment: @Takeshi Yes, lowest total score wins; if players are negative that doesn't change.